# Visual Studio 2015 won't install correctly (.NET Framework 4.6 Error)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

Today (and many days before) I tried to install Visual Studio 2015, but with no luck. I constantly get an error saying that I my system does not have .NET Framework 4.6 installed.

After searching some posts on Stack Overflow I found some people that had the same problem but their questions weren't awnsered with the correct fix. I obviously tried Google in the first place but no fixes were found.

***For example:***

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160022/visual-studio-2015-wont-install
- http://stackOverflow.com/questions/31586403/visual-studio-2015-does-not-start-missing-net-framework-4-6 (*note*: thorn's awnser)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/193a3f93-fb98-4d9a-ba7a-b54c6cffd41f/error-code-0x80070001-while-installing-visual-studio-2015-on-window-81?forum=vssetup 
  (Clearing the %TEMP% folder and manually installing Framework 4.6 does not work either.)

### Installing Visual Studio 2015

Please see the screenshots that I've made during the installation.

*Step 1* Installation details: 
[image]
*Step 2* Stuck at *Applying Framework*:
[image]
*Step 3* The Error: 
[image]

 **It says that this part is *NOT* installed on my system.**
So I looked and it wasn't installed.

But if I look in my installed programs it clearly shows Visual Studio 2015 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XCsm.png).

### Installing .NET Framework 4.6

So I tried to install this framework manually.
The online *and* offline setup give me the same error:

 Setup failed.

Installing: i.stack.imgur.com/XplBw.png
Rollback?!: i.stack.imgur.com/RdNyz.png
Failed: i.stack.imgur.com/lu3x8.png

### Computer specifications

OS: Windows 8.1 (64-bit, Dutch) 
Motherboard: Asus Maximus Formula VII
RAM: 16 GB (1600Mhz) Corsair Vengeance

### Notes

- There is enough space on my SSD for the program to install
- Using an SSD
- I am not going to upgrade to Windows 10 in order to fix this issue (if that is the case)
- I tried Visual Studio 2015 Community from the official Microsoft website *and* the Visual Studio 2015 Community from Dreamspark (since I am a student)

### Log info

this is the error in the log:

```
[08A8:09E4][2016-03-10T15:35:13]i301: Applying execute package: netfxfullweb, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\NetFxWeb393297\packages\dotNetFramework\dotNetFx-Web.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\NetFxWeb393297\packages\dotNetFramework\dotNetFx-Web.exe" /q /norestart /KeepAUPaused /lcid 1033 /ChainingPackage vs_community /log C:\Users\TERRYD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20160310153449_135_netfxfullweb.log.html'
[08A8:09E4][2016-03-10T15:36:02]e000: Error 0x800736b3: Process returned error: 0x36b3
[08A8:09E4][2016-03-10T15:36:02]e000: Error 0x800736b3: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1770:0634][2016-03-10T15:36:02]e000: Error 0x800736b3: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1770:0634][2016-03-10T15:36:02]i000: MUX: Installation size in bytes for package: netfxfullweb MaxAppDrive: 0 MaxSysDrive: 687198208 AppDrive: 0 SysDrive: 44032000
[1770:0634][2016-03-10T15:36:02]i000: MUX: Return Code:0x800736B3 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1770:0634][2016-03-10T15:36:02]i000: MUX: Set Result: Return Code=-2147010893 (0x800736B3), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=netfxfullweb<br><br>
```

Log

Comment: What is in the logfile?

Comment: I've uploaded the log here: http://tinyurl.com/jnzjt2v

Comment: couldn't you find a less ad infected site? NSFW for me ...

Comment: I've uploaded it on mediafire(http://tinyurl.com/jnzjt2v) and on OneDrive(http://1drv.ms/1YBFvqp)... What do you prefer?

Comment: anyway. it looks like your PC is missing some essentials the 4.6 installer is expecting. Some suggest an initial .Net 3.5 install might work or use the suggestion offered [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/errorsxsassemblynotfound-0x800736b3-installing/735140b2-ce4b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1)

Comment: you get this error: 0x800736B3 = ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND. share this log file: C:\Users\TERRYD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20160310153449_135_netfxfullweb.log.html

Comment: Try these steps:  1- clear entirely your "AppData\Local\Temp" (but keep the folder) and also "Windows\temp".   2- Check if Environment is OK: Right-button on Start Button, System, Advanced, ENvironment Variables. Check if TEMP is defined, TMP is defined and PATH is less than 512 chars.   3- Download Windows Installer 4.5 for Windows 8 (search Google).   If nothing of these solve the problem, CHKDSK.